# Align span element in Bootstrap 5 button groups

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

The span elements of the button groups don't align with each other. I would like to align the span elements of the button groups without using fixed widths.

Simple web modal using Bootstrap 5

[image: 1]

```html
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic checkbox toggle button group">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="mode"><i class="bi bi-palette"></i> &nbsp;
        Mode</span>

    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="modeOptions" id="artist" autocomplete="off" checked>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="artist" onclick="displayType = 1;"
        data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-html="true"
        title="Play and Store Notes">Artist</label>

    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="modeOptions" id="perfectionModeautocomplete=" off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="perfectionMode" onclick="displayType = 2;"
        data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-html="true"
        title="Play along mode">Perfection</label>
</div>
<br> <br>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic checkbox toggle button group">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="bi bi-music-note-list"></i> &nbsp;
        Notation Type</span>

    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="options" id="staffNotation" autocomplete="off"
        checked>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="staffNotation" onclick="displayType = 1;">Staff
        Notation</label>

    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="options" id="abcNotation" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="abcNotation" onclick="displayType = 2;">ABC
        Notation</label>

    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="options" id="srgNotation" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="srgNotation" onclick="displayType = 3;">Custom
        Notation</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and specifically how to create a [minimally, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help you without some code. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using `table` with `tr` and `td` elements. It will help those groups of buttons will be neatly arranged.

```css
label {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-icons/1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic checkbox toggle button group">
        <td>
          <span class="input-group-text" id="mode"><i class="bi bi-palette"></i> &nbsp;
            Mode</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="modeOptions" id="artist" autocomplete="off" checked>
          <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="artist" onclick="displayType = 1;"
            data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-html="true"
            title="Play and Store Notes">Artist</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="modeOptions" id="perfectionMode" autocomplete="off">
          <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="perfectionMode" onclick="displayType = 2;"
              data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-html="true"
              title="Play along mode">Perfection</label>
        </td>
    </div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic checkbox toggle button group">
        <td>
          <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="bi bi-music-note-list"></i> &nbsp;
            Notation Type</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="options" id="staffNotation" autocomplete="off"
              checked>
          <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="staffNotation" onclick="displayType = 1;">Staff
              Notation</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="options" id="abcNotation" autocomplete="off">
          <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="abcNotation" onclick="displayType = 2;">ABC
              Notation</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="options" id="srgNotation" autocomplete="off">
          <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="srgNotation" onclick="displayType = 3;">Custom
              Notation</label>
        </td>
    </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Using HTML tables for layout is a bad idea. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics#when_should_you_not_use_html_tables

Comment: The alignment cannot be done with a table as it would break the bootstrap alignment and style.